# PyCharm not hitting Quick and Dirty breakpoint on "pass"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, breakpoints

I want to add a quick & dirty breakpoint, e.g when I am interested in stopping in the middle of iterating a long list.

```
for item in list:
    if item == 'curry':
        pass
```

I put a breakpoint on `pass`, and it is not hit(!).

If I add a following (empty) print

```
for item in list:
    if item = 'curry':
        pass
        print('')
```

and breakpoint both `pass` and `print`, only `print` is hit.

Any idea why?  Windows 7, (portable) Python 3.7

---

[Update] as per the comment form @Adam.Er8 I tried inserting and breakpointing the ellipsis literal, `...` but that was not hit, although the following `print('')` was.

---

[Updtae++]  Hmm, it ***does*** hit a breakpoint on the `pass in`

```
for key, value in dictionary.items(): 
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing `pass` with `...`:

```py
for item in list:
    if item = 'curry':
        ...
```

you should be able to break-point there

this is called the [ellipsis literal](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/constants.html#Ellipsis), unlike `pass` it is actually "executed" (well, sort of), and this is why you can break on it, like you would on any other statement, but it has 0 side effects and reads like "nothing" (before discovering this trick I'd just write `_ = 0`)

**EDIT:**

you can just set a conditional breakpoint.

In PyCharm this is done by right-clicking the bp and writing the condition:
[image]

Comment: Oops, my bad, sorry. I just typed that code in as an example; I did not coy it from real code. Of course I would use a test for equality, rather than assignment. I have updated the question.  You are helping to narrow it down, as a breakpoint on `...` is also not hit

Comment: hmmm... I'd suspect some optimization but this goes into depths I seem to not know a lot about :(

Answer (score 4):

The `pass` doesn't actually make it into the bytecode. The code is exactly the same as if it wasn't there. You can see this using the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module. (examples using 3.7 on linux).

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(dis.dis('for i in a:\n\tprint("i")')                                                                                               
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 22)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              4 GET_ITER
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                12 (to 20)
              8 STORE_NAME               1 (i)

  2          10 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 ('i')
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 POP_TOP
             18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   20 POP_BLOCK
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('for i in a:\n\tpass\n\tprint("i")')                                                                                       
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 22)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              4 GET_ITER
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                12 (to 20)
              8 STORE_NAME               1 (i)

  3          10 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 ('i')
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 POP_TOP
             18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   20 POP_BLOCK
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

What the bytecode is doing isn't as relevant as the fact both blocks are identical. the `pass` is just ignored so there is nothing for the debugger to break on.

Comment: I could swear that this used to work!  Any better suggestions than `print('')` ?

Comment: Presumably you are already doing something in the loop? Can't you break on that?

Comment: That's the point.  I don't want to break every time through the loop; only on a given value of what I am looping over. Please also see the latest update to the question. Thanks